# Node JS Http response streaming handling

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working on the sensortag devices, I need to get the sensor values continuously from the device.
Here I am using the Angular JS & node JS. from the Angular JS I am requesting the node JS to response back the sensor values. Because the sensor is running with the help of Node JS.
My requesting code is

```
$http.get('http://node js url/sensortag device id')
       .success(function(response) {
        console.log('message from node',response);
       })
       .error(function() {
        });
```

and from the node js, I am using the response.write() but is not useful to me. It will send the data at the time stopping/closing the connection.
I need the continuous responses back.

Please help me out. I got stuck here.

Is http steaming helpful ? and how to use that one.

Other wise let me know if any other way to request the node to keep sending the data

Comment: Why don't you use WebSockets for this ?

Comment: If I use the sockets, then how to handle the multiple users

Comment: You can pass data using WebSockets, not just events. See: http://socket.io/docs/ for examples.

Comment: I can use sockets, but here my client is in AngularJS. Then, How can I get the socket.io in angularJS, because it is node. Right?